# Calculate definite integral of a product of ~30 linear functions as precisely as possible?

Tags: calculus, computational-mathematics

So, I've got this polynomial:
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x-b_i}{k_i}, k_i,b_i\in\mathbb{N}$$
I need to calculate its definite integral on some segment $[a;b], a\geq 0$ and it's guaranteed that every linear function takes values from $[0;1]$ on that segment.

Right now I'm just expanding the product and calculating the antiderivative as usual, but it gives me enormous precision errors when I try to calculate the antiderivative at $a$ and $b$.

It happens because the result should be a positive number not exceeding $1$, but all terms $a_ix^i$ of the expanded polynomial are huge numbers with strictly alternating signs (because of $b_i$ being positive).

Obviously, adding them up is a bad idea.
Is there some cool math trick to overcome this?

Comment: If every linear function has maximal value $1$ in the interval $[a,b]$ then the value of the function and the integral will be really small. If we just assume that the average is $1/2$, then the product of 1000 of them would be on the order of $2^{-1000}$ or around $10^{-300}$, well below typical machine precision.

Comment: Oh shit, I've messed up. It's not even 1000 of them, only 20 or so are actually used - and it's enough to give this error. Will fix in a moment.

Comment: If it is only 20 or so than you only get a polynomial of degree 20, no fun to integrate by hand but it shouldn't be hard for a computer algebra program.

Comment: I need to code it without using CAS and naive integration gives the problem described in the question: adding large numbers of opposite signs.

Comment: Then I would use some approximation, instead of the exact integral. For example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule . Evaluating the polynomial at individual points should be numerically stable and with enough of them you can get a very good approximation.

Comment: I need O(n) solution. Dividing $[a;b]$ into a number of smaller segments is inacceptable.

Comment: Multiplying out the polynomial already takes $2^n$ steps, so I don't think you can get $O(n)$.

Comment: What? No it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following

\begin{equation}
\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x-b_i}{k_i} = e^{\log\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{x-b_i}{k_i} \right)} = e^{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log\left(\frac{x-b_i}{k_i} \right)}. 
\end{equation}

Since every linear functional is between $[0,1]$ the logarithm is well defined. Depending on what program/library you're using, the numerical integration for special functions might be able to deal with the numerical precision errors you are having.

Comment: I've thought about numerical integration already. My solution is already borderline too slow, I don't want to make it even slower by calculating polynomial-ish stuff on a number of points.